# ¿Cómo obtengo varios atributos en un XML? en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, parsear, parser

Tengo un archivo xml (es una factura) necesito extraer los datos con **python** y utilizo minidom, sin embargo, en la parte de concepto que son varios (de acuerdo a la compra o venta que se realice) sólo me trae los atributos del primero. Muchas gracias!

Necesito si en el archivo XML vienen 2 o más "cfdi:Concepto" extraer todos los atributos que contengan.

**archivo XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" Version="3.3" Folio="114255" Fecha="2021-11-13T09:13:05"   CondicionesDePago="CONTADO" SubTotal="177.90" Moneda="MXN" Total="206.36" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="31150">
<cfdi:Emisor Rfc="XAXX010101000" Nombre="COMERCIALIZADORA EJEMPLO S.A. DE C.V." RegimenFiscal="601"/>
<cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XAXX010101111" Nombre="IMPORTADORA EJEMPLO S.A DE C.V" UsoCFDI="G03"/>
<cfdi:Conceptos>
# NECESITO LOS ATRIBUTOS DE ESTE "cfdi:Concepto"(1)
<cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="12161902" NoIdentificacion="185406" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="Pieza" Descripcion="DETERGENTE ARCOIRIS 9 KG." ValorUnitario="158.00" Importe="158.00">
        <cfdi:Impuestos>
            <cfdi:Traslados>
                <cfdi:Traslado Base="158.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="25.28"/>
            </cfdi:Traslados>
        </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Concepto>
# NECESITO LOS ATRIBUTOS DE ESTE "cfdi:Concepto"(2)
<cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="47131816" NoIdentificacion="1357" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="Pieza" Descripcion="PASTILLA C/GANCHO 60 GRS. WIESE" ValorUnitario="7.90" Importe="7.90">
        <cfdi:Impuestos>
            <cfdi:Traslados>
                <cfdi:Traslado Base="7.90" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="1.264"/>
            </cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Concepto>
# NECESITO LOS ATRIBUTOS DE ESTE "cfdi:Concepto"(3)
<cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="47131605" NoIdentificacion="25600" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="Pieza" Descripcion="CEPILLO T/PLANCHA" ValorUnitario="12.00" Importe="12.00">
        <cfdi:Impuestos>
            <cfdi:Traslados>
                <cfdi:Traslado Base="12.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="1.92"/>
            </cfdi:Traslados>
        </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Concepto>
</cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="28.46">
    <cfdi:Traslados>
        <cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="28.46"/>
    </cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Complemento><tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital</cfdi:Complemento></cfdi:Comprobante>
```

**CODIGO PARA EXTRAER DATOS**

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml= '/Users/HERNAN/facturas/ejemplo.xml'
mytree=minidom.parse(xml)
tagname=mytree.getElementsByTagName('cfdi:Concepto')[0]
descripcion= tagname.attributes['Descripcion'].value
print(descripcion)
cantidad= tagname.attributes['Cantidad'].value
print(cantidad)
importe= tagname.attributes['Importe'].value
print(importe)
```

**RESULTADO EN CONSOLA**

```
DETERGENTE ARCOIRIS 9 KG.
1
158.00
```

Comment: Hola! Ese XML es inválido en la última línea `<cfdi:Complemento><tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital</cfd` y tu código falla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es sencillo. No recibas el elemento cero sino todos; ya después puedes iterar

```py
from xml.dom import minidom

xml= 'fuente.xml'
mytree=minidom.parse(xml)
tags=mytree.getElementsByTagName('cfdi:Concepto')
for tagname in tags:
    descripcion= tagname.attributes['Descripcion'].value
    print(descripcion)
    cantidad= tagname.attributes['Cantidad'].value
    print(cantidad)
    importe= tagname.attributes['Importe'].value
    print(importe)
```

Esto da como salida:

```
DETERGENTE ARCOIRIS 9 KG.
1
158.00
PASTILLA C/GANCHO 60 GRS. WIESE
1
7.90
CEPILLO T/PLANCHA
1
12.00
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!